# Cannot open an excel file for which I clicked view > hide on mac. All the other files open just fine

Tags: excel, macos, hide

I cannot open my excel file, for which I clicked view > checked "hide" when I had the file open previously.

As soon i did that, the file stopped displaying. Every time I click the file, Excel software starts running, so I don't think there is anything wrong with the software itself, just a problem with this specific file. All the other excel files would open when I click them, except this one.

I am using a macboook pro.

Could anyone please help me how to undo the action I did? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The view-hide literally hides the file from being seen when opened and I didn't know that....